# Running a jsp website on Tomcat server in Eclipse - how to run a Main method upon server start-up?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have a JSP webpage being run on a Tomcat server in Eclipse. The website has a Java back-end which it communicates with through Servlets. Everything works fine, but I'd like to have a background process running - say, a Main method. This method should start upon server start-up.

The reason I need this is as follows: Say the webpage has different users log in, and I want to track their user names and do something with them - maybe create sessions to track some metrics.

I realize that one way to do this might be to check if our method is running every time somebody logs in. Like so:

```java
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 if (/* Method is not initialized */)
      /*call Method*/
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do start this background method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your process at deployment time of your webapp. To achieve this, you have to create a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Just create a class:

```
public class YourClassName implements ServletContextListener{


    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    run your background stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    stop your background stuff

    }
}
```

And define it in your web.xml:

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                 your class fully qualified name
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

And if you don't want to bother writing the XML definition and you are running Java 6+, you could also annotate your class with

```
@WebListener
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want/need to run a process when deploying you application, you must define a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). But from your requirement details, seems that you need a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to start trackign each user session start. From its javadoc:

> Interface for receiving notification events about `HttpSession` lifecycle changes. (...) Implementations of this interface are invoked at their `sessionCreated(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)` method in the order in which they have been declared, and at their `sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)` method in reverse order.

And probably you may check changes in session attributes as well, so use a [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) to accomplish this.